# Custom view button in navigation bar has unwanted top margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm creating a custom view, which needs to be clickable, hence the button, and need to be in the left at the navigation bar (so, I replace the leftBarButtonItem).

If I add my custom view, to a UIBarButtonItem with - (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView;, the placement is exactly what I want, but I can't "click" on it. If I add my custom view as an UIButton subView, and use the button in the UIBarButtonItem - (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView; I can click on it, but now my cusotm view has a topmargin of aproximately 26 points, exceeding the navigationBar height.

This has the correct position, but can't click on it

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
....
UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customButton;
```

This has the wrong position, but can click on it

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
....
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addSubview:customView];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(userProfile) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customButton;
```

[image: Case 1: Good positioning]
[image: Case 2: Bad positioning]

Hope I have made myself clear. I'm really clueless with this. I've tried forcing imageEdgeInsets in the UIButton, modifying the frame "y" origin making it negative... but nothing works.

EDIT: @kschaeffer solution works. Just needed to set the button frame the same as the customView frame.

**This no longer works in iOs 7**

In this case, it gets an unwanted left margin, and stops being clickable (no touch event gets recorded for the button as far as I see)

[image: Bug description iOs 7]

Comment: is it possible show enable the border for each view. with view.layer.bordercolor = .. and view.layer.borderwith = .. ?

Comment: what frames do you specify for the custom view and the button?

Comment: I have added the frame for the customView, and I don't specify a frame for the UIButton. 
@CarlJ I'll try to add an image with the borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the customButton frame the same as the custom view. This actually works for me.

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
UIButton *customButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:customView.bounds];

[customButton addTarget:target action:@selector(userProfile) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customView addSubview:customButton];

UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
```

Comment: sadly don't work for me. If use initWithBarButtonSystemItem and initWithCustomView together.